# Return the result of each iteration in the loop

Tags: java, loops, getter-setter, getter

I'm doing something that produces the right result. However, it is wrong from a design POV.

The point of the program is to list the result of all the powers of a number up to and including the user-defined limit.

I have a constructor which accepts the base and the exponent from the Scanner. Then a method, which utilises a for loop to calculate the power for each exponent.

Now, the problem is that I'm printing the result from each loop iteration directly from this method. This beats the point of private variables and it being void in the 1st place.

Therefore, I want to define a getter method which returns the result of each power to the output. I used to set them just fine for if/switch statements, but I don't know how to do the same for loops. If I assign the result to a variable within the loop and return that variable from the getter then it will return only the output from the final iteration.

Private implementation

```
package Chapter6Review;

public class Powers {

private int target;
private int power;


public Powers(int target, int power) {
    this.target = target;
    this.power = power;
}

public void calculatePower() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++) {
        System.out.println((int) Math.pow(target, i)); 
    }
}

/*
public int getPower() {
    return 
}
*/
}
```

User interface

```
package Chapter6Review;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PowersTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your base: ");
    int target = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter your exponent: ");
    int power = in.nextInt();

    Powers tester = new Powers(target, power);
    tester.calculatePower();

}
}
```

Comment: You can collect the result in a List and after the loop you can return the list itself and iterate through it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a List ;

```
public List<Integer> calculatePower() {

    int p;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++) {
        p = (int) Math.pow(target, i); 
        result.add(p);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then in you main method, you can iterate the list to print the powers like that :

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Powers tester = new Powers(target, power);
result = tester.calculatePower();

for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(result.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Good ;) just as comment, can reduce as `result.add( (int) Math.pow(target, i) );`

Comment: @Harish depend of coder ;) Perso I prefer, less variables in code, less variables in memory, less lines, less operation .. but depend of coders, that's why I said "can reduce" and no "please reduce" ;)

Comment: @azro Roger that. Thanks.( I wasn't sure I could freely cast in the method parameter that why I hesitated).

Comment: @azro less variables in code ? here is only one extra variable. less lines ?the method is hardly 10 lines.less operations ? even the single set does the same number of operations. Just saying!

Comment: @Harish because you stay focus on this method .. sure that if you look method one by one you would keep lines, but as the class in its globality I'm talking, debate closed

Comment: lol Yeah debated close...This is not about algorithm time complexity guyz. Relax... Harish, the more a program is complex, the more azro's pov is expected....Azro the less a program is complex, with the current state of technology, the more Harish's pov is right...You both won. ;-)

Comment: @azro my statement was the OP's POV else you are right. Jason sorry for filling your Answer with loads of comments

Comment: @JasonKrs thanks, that might be the best solution for this.

Comment: @Dorkymon I'm glad it'll help. You could accept the answer to show your appreciation (or at least vote up). I saw your answer below. It's also a nice option. Good work ;-)

Comment: @JasonKrs thanks, I upvoted every answer in this thread actually and you should have received reputation for that, but it won't publicly show on the page since my account has less than 15 reputation. I went with the list in the end since arrays and array lists are the next chapter in my book anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could store each of the results in a List:

```
List<Power> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and when you call it add it as well

```
list.add(new Powers(target, power));
```

At the end you can iterate over the list like this:

```
for (Power power : list){
// your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using streams as well

```
public List<Integer> calculatePower() {
    return IntStream
            .rangeClosed(0, power). // iterate from 0 till power inclusive
            .mapToObj(i -> (int) Math.pow(target,i)) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // get result as list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. Using a list seems to be a good choice.
Since I haven't covered lists yet, I resorted to this solution for now. But I don't like having code that can affect the solution in the main. Ideally, the loop should go in the private implementation.

Main

```
    Powers tester = new Powers(target, power);

    for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++) {
        tester.calculatePower(i);
        System.out.println(tester.getPower());
    }
```

Private implementation

```
public void calculatePower(int iPower) {
    result = (int) Math.pow(target, iPower);
}

public int getPower() {
    return result;
}
```